# av_open_input_file returns -2 but file exists (libav in NS2)

Tags: ns2, libavformat, libav

I try to make a simulation in NS2 in which i read in .wav files, encodes into gsm and send   them over the network. I already managed to make an application that reads in .wav, encodes into gsm and stores on the hard drive (tested, works fine). Now i try to do the same extending the Network Simulator 2 and i have a problem with av_open_input_file which constantly says there is no such file, although i had no problems with that file in my gsm encoding application. The call i use:

```
av_open_input_file(&pFormatCtx, "/home/xxx/audio_samples/audio.wav", NULL, 0, NULL);
```

Already tried different files, hardcoding the path, absolute path, relative path and putting "file://" in front because libav apparently uses some sort of file protocol. Then I tried opening the file myself with:

```
int desc = open("/home/xxx/audio_samples/audio.wav", O_RDONLY, 0);
```

(found this call in file.c of libav that is supposed to be called by av_open_input_file) No problems with opening the file like that, everything seems to be ok, so now i have no idea what else could be wrong.

Any suggestions?

Best regards,
florencka

Answer (score 3):

Problem solved. av_register_all() was missing before calling av_open_input_file. There was no warning or error though.

Comment: How could it have warned you :)